# Are homogeneous holomorphic functions necessarily polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ be holomorphic. If

$$h (\lambda z)= \lambda ^d h (z) $$

Always for non zero $\lambda  $, is h a homogeneous polynomial?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will lead you in the correct direction but consider a power series expansion around the origin for both sides of your equation. Think about how to factor out $\lambda$ to make this work.

Comment: This is why it should be true, but how do I know that power series expansions behave that way?

Comment: Assuming that $d \in \Bbb{R}$, I guess this may work: If $d \leq 0$, then by the Liouville's theorem we may conclude that $f$ is constant. Now we may use the Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions to inductively prove that this is true for all $d$.